# Is there a specific word for a person who tries to tell you what you think or believe?

Tags: terminology

Is there a specific word for a person who tries to tell you what you think or believe?

Comment: Your second question about professional help is a matter of opinion and is not appropriate on a forum about the English language. I have therefore edited your question to remove that sentence.  As regards your first question, please read the Help pages and indicate what research you have done on that question.

Comment: I suppose "conceited ass" is two words.

Comment: ^Lol - but yeah I definitely know what this question's getting at and can think of a few people who fit the bill, but I'm stumped as to a specific word for this.

Comment: To use language in attempts to influence what others think or believe is to engage in *rhetoric;* and, far from being abnormal or pathological, it is essential to being human. As I often tell students in my graduate seminar in rhetorical theory, every two-year-old knows that the true function of language is to influence others to do what we want, and not to communicate objective truth to them. If in verbally attempting so to manipulate others you merely annoy them, that is counter-productive, and in that case perhaps you do need professional help--from a rhetorician if not a psychotherapist.

Comment: A street magician. An arrogant ''mind reader.'' A ''clairvoyant.'' A ''proselytizer.'' please come up with more context and by more, I mean at least one.

Comment: Are you asking about mentors and others who listen to your attempts at articulating your own thoughts and beliefs, and then help you rephrase to be more coherent?

Answer (score 0):

This question is impossible to answer without context. @vickyace pointed out *proselytizer* which is a person who attempts to convert someone. I believe by saying "tries to tell you what to think" you mean someone who has malicious intent. In that, *manipulator* fits the best.

Answer (score 0):

'pedagogue' is a word for teacher but implies a one-way flow of information with little respect for the student.

Answer (score -1):

I agree that the context is very important.  I like manipulator and proselytizer.  I would add to that zealot, someone who is overzealous/fanatical about an idea, ideal, cause, etc.  Zealots tend to be proselytizers in the first degree.  They believe everyone should think as they do.